# Why the initial value did not change?

Tags: javascript

Help please, why the initial value did not change?
*For some reason if I remove clock "else" everything works fine.

```js
    var value = 0;

    function f() {
        if (true) {
            value = 15;
        }
        else {
            var value = false;
        }
        console.log('changed value',value);
    }

    f();
    console.log('value ',value);
```

Comment: `var value = false;` <-- what do you think that `var` is doing? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: Note that this is one reason why almost all modern JavaScript uses `let` instead of `var`. `var` has a lot of confusing behavior that leads to weird bugs like this.

Comment: See [Understanding Hoisting](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript) and [Variable Scope](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/).

Comment: Thanks everyone for help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), the var moves the declaration to the top of the function. So instead of value being the reference to the global, it is now scoped to your function.  So your code actually looks like this:

```js
var value = 0;

function f() {
  var value;
  if (true) {
    value = 15;
  } else {
    value = false;
  }
  console.log('changed value', value);
}

f();
console.log('value ', value);
```

To solve it, you need to get rid of the `var` inside your function.

```js
var value = 0;

function f() {
  if (true) {
    value = 15;
  } else {
    value = false;
  }
  console.log('changed value', value);
}

f();
console.log('value ', value);
```

Comment: Interesting; in the original code, even if only the `false` version has the `var` declaration, and is never actually hit (since `if(true)` is `true`), hoisting still occurs?

Comment: Cool :) I've never seen the term before; good to know, and yet another reason to use `let` or `const` vs `var`.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! =)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `var` you create a new variable. If you want to change the existing variable, remove `var`:

```js
var value = 0;

function f() {
  if (true) {
    value = 15;
  } else {
    value = false;
  }
  console.log('changed value', value);
}

f();
console.log('value ', value);
```

Of course `true` will always be true, so it will always be 15.

Answer (score 1):

On your code `var value = false;` is the problem.

Updated code.

```
    var value = 0;

    function f() {
        if (true) {
            value = 15;
        }
        else {
            value = false;
        }
        console.log('changed value',value);
    }

    f();
    console.log('value ',value);
```

Comment: It is allowed, that's why the code runs. It just isn't doing what they expected.

Comment: And you just told same thing on other question, stop saying that... It is allowed...